# Docker doesn't start MONGODB, and IPAddress doesn't appear, when started with other services

Tags: mongodb, rabbitmq, docker, sshd, systemd

I have already asked this question on serverfault.com. I am asking it here too as I see different set of questions in these 2 sites (it appears like they have different databases).

I have been trying to build an OS image from Fedora unsuccessfully to start the following:

1. Systemd
2. SSHD
3. RabbitMQ
4. MongoDB

I can get the first 3 (Systemd, SSHD and RabbitMQ-Server) to work. I can also get MongoDB to work within the container. However, I cannot get MongoDB to work along with other 3 services.

In addition, IP address doesn't show up when I try to "dockerize" MongoDB.

Am I missing something in the Dockerfile?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:20
MAINTAINER “Ashfaque” <ashfaque@email.com>
ENV container docker
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install systemd; yum clean all; \
(cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

# Dockerizing SSH - is working
RUN yum -y install openssh-server
RUN yum -y install openssh-clients
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN systemctl enable sshd.service
RUN echo 'root:mypassword' |chpasswd
EXPOSE 22

# Dockerizing RabbitMQ - is working
RUN yum -y install rabbitmq-server
EXPOSE 5672 15672
RUN systemctl enable rabbitmq-server

# Dockerizing MongoDB - is NOT WORKING
RUN yum -y install mongodb-server
RUN yum -y install boost
RUN yum -y install scons
# Create the MongoDB data directory
RUN mkdir -p /data/db /var/log/mongodb /var/run/mongodb
RUN sed -i 's/dbpath =\/var\/lib\/mongodb/dbpath =\/data\/db/' /etc/mongodb.conf
# Expose port 27017 from the container to the host
EXPOSE 27017
# Set usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
#CMD ["--port", "27017", "--dbpath", "/data/db", "--smallfiles", "--fork", "--syslog"]
#RUN /usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --fork --syslog

VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup", "/data/db", "/var/log/mongodb", "/usr/bin"]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Docker Commands used to build are:

(1) `docker build -t rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug .`

(2) `docker run --privileged -d -e 'container=docker' -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 29022:22 -p 29672:15672 -p 29017:27017 rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug`

or.. (3) `docker run --privileged -ti -e 'container=docker' -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p 29022:22 -p 29672:15672 -p 29017:27017 rabbitmq_mongo_heisenbug`

Comment: Some information on what exactly is failing while running / starting-up MongoDB will be useful to suggest anything. Any logs that point to that? are you able to install MongoDB and then failing to start it or the other way.

Comment: When I run in interactive mode, it throws an error: "Invalid command: /usr/sbin/init". In the daemon more, I cannot SSH into the container (as it wouldn't have started and IP address would not be taken up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` in your Dockerfile. This means, that docker will run `/usr/bin/mongod` with default parameter `/usr/sbin/init`. I'm pretty sure this is not what you want.

Docker will run as long as the command you specified is running. I'm not sure about `/usr/bin/mongod`, but if it runs in daemon mode (that is, spawn a process and return), then the container will stop running right away. The spawned processes will be terminated. The same is true for `/usr/sbin/init` or for any other command you specify. You can write a small shell script, which spawns the processes and runs one in the foreground, or you can use [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/), or some similar tool.

Also, you probably don't need to run `sshd` in your container. See [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) why.

Comment: Thanks for the informative response. 

SSH: I need SSH, as I want 3 of my daemons to run within the container (along with rabbitmq/etc), & later run 2 other applications after logging in.

I have a question here - Is it not a right approach to run several daemons?

MongoDB:
I did try having CMD (it is commented out to indicate some of the trial-and-error scenarios that I had attempted. e.g. I had 1 CMD separated by commas)

    CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"] ["/usr/sbin/init", "--port", "27017", "--dbpath", "/data/db", "--smallfiles", "--fork", "--syslog"]

Is there a right approach for this scenario?

Comment: Actually, your response answered my question. Thanks! I could set it up after reading your response.

Here is what I did:
1. Commented out ENTRYPOINT
2. Run the following commands in the container:
    chown mongod:mongod /data/db
    chmod 0755 /data/db
    useradd mongodb
    groupadd mongodb
    chown mongod:mongod /data/db
    systemctl start mongod.service
    touch /data/db/mongod.lock
    chown mongod:mongod /data/db/mongod.lock
    /usr/bin/mongod --smallfiles
I pulled this out from history in the container. Some might be redundant and not necessary; they throw out an error anyways.